# Funny observations with cmd.exe and redirection

Tags: redirect, cmd, stdout, stdin, stderr

Can anyone explain this behaviour of the Windows Command processor:

Open cmd.exe
Type for example:

```
echo Hello 0>my.txt
```

Result:
An empty file named "my.txt"
Repeat this but replace '0' by the digits '1' to '9'

Observation: Just the same, an empty file.

Then replace the '0' by '10'
Observation: File 'my.txt' now contains the line "Hello 10"

Then rework the redirection statement like:

```
    echo >my.txt Hello 0
```

Observation: File 'my.txt' now contains the line "Hello 0"

Question: WHY do the single digits before the '>' let the line get swallowed?

(I did this on Win7, but quite optimistic that its not version dependent)

Comment: Because `>` is not technically correct, you should be using `1>` for standard text output. So if you wanted to print `Hello 0` to `my.txt` you should use `(Echo Hello 0) 1>"my.txt"` or `1>"my.txt" Echo Hello 0`. If you choose the latter, beware of accidental trailing spaces on the line, _`1>"my.txt" (Echo Hello 0)` would be safer_.

Comment: As an addition to my previous comment, should you therefore need to output a closing parenthesis within your text, that would need to be escaped in order for it not to prematurely close the intended parentheses pair. So if you wanted to print `A) Say Hello` to `my.txt` you'd use `(Echo A^) Say Hello) 1>"my.txt"`, or `1>"my.txt" (Echo A^) Say Hello)`.

Comment: @Compo very well explained and in depth! Thx a lot!